# Powershell, Get-ChildItem from today only

Tags: date, powershell

What's the best way to grab files from today only in Powershell? I have this:

```
$file_list = gci $foldern | where {([datetime]::now - $_.lastwritetime).TotalHours -lt 24};
```

But it grabs files from the last 24 hours, and not quite "today".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just check the date?

```
$file_list = gci $foldern | where {([datetime]::now.Date -eq $_.lastwritetime.Date)};
```

Comment: Or `[datetime]::today -le $_.lastwritetime` since `[datetime]::today` will give you exactly midnight for the current day.

Comment: That's a good way too. I would write it the other way around `$_.lastwritetime -ge [datetime]::today` because I think "greater than" is clearer to me. It may just be how my mind works.